# Creating reminders/notifications in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications

We're building an intranet in Ruby on Rails and now we want to add functionality for having reminders when you should have done something but haven't.

For example, say you have a model, Meeting, I want to send reminders to everyone who has had a meeting but where the meeting report is empty (`meeting.date < Date.today && meeting.report == ""`). And a project model where you have some other criteria (maybe `project.last_report.date < lastMonday && !project.closed`)

Now, I can imagine creating these reminders with some kind of rake task and then removing them by some event trigger when you update Meeting or whatever, but that seems like I'll get spaghetti code everywhere.

My second idea is to make a separate module that, on each page load, fetches all the entries that could be related and runs all these checks, and then returns Reminders, however, this will probably be hella slow to hit the database like this. (Maybe caching would be an option but still)

So, anybody done something like this and have any ideas on how to solve our problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any issue with spaghetti code if you let each object that requires a Reminder to manage it's own reminders.  If you want to be an OOP purist you could probably create a separate class (e.g., MeetingReminderManager in your example) to manage the reminders but that seems like overkill here.  Consider...

```
class Reminder
  belongs_to :source, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Meeting
  has_many :reminders, as: :source
  has_many :users

  after_create :build_reminders, if: ->{|meeting| meeting.report.blank? }
  after_update :destroy_reminders, if: ->{|meeting| !meeting.report.blank? }

  private
    def build_reminders
      users.each{|user| self.reminders.create user_id: user.id, due_on: self.date }
    end

    def destroy_reminders
      self.reminders.delete_all
    end
end
```

Comment: Ok so 1 potential problem here would be that I need a meeting to have a reminder only after the meeting has passed. So there would still need to be some kind of enormous rake task to be run once/hour to create all the new reminders?

Comment: An alternate look: create the reminders immediately (as shown) and only display/take action on the reminders when the 'due_on' date (or due_at time) has passed.  Note that the code shown also removes the reminders when their requirements have been fulfilled so the user would not see the reminder if they fulfilled the requirements in a timely manner.  This is _much_ simpler.

Comment: I guess. You could also add some specialized classes to some kind of reminders/ directory and include them as mixins, which would generate no code ugliness too. All in all, your solution seems valid!

Comment: I always err on the _simplest_ possible solution and then build in complexity as the use cases demand it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with spaghetti and background job in ruby on rails. I think making them is the path to go. Check whatever is suit you: http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=32